# Proof that every group of order $15,400$ has a normal subgroup of order $275$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I constructed the groups of order $15,400=2^3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\cdot 11$ with GAP and noticed that every such group has a normal subgroup of order $275=5^2\cdot 11$.

> Can this be proven by hand ?

Motivation :

With this information, we can conclude via the Hall-theorem, that every group of order $15,400$ is a semidirect product of a group of order $275=5^2\cdot11$ and a group of order $56=2^3\cdot 7$.

Furthermore, using the Burnside theorem, it follows that every group of order $15,400$ is solvable.

Comment: I am sure that it can be done by hand, but I am not planning to do it! I suggest starting off as follows. The number of Sylow $5$-subgroups is $1,11,56$ or $616$. If it is $56$ or $616$ then the group has a normal $5$-complement by Burnside's Transfer Theorem. If it is $11$, then there must be an element of order $7$ in the kernel of the conjugation action on them, and we get a normal subgroup of order $7$. If it is $1$ then there is a normal subgroup of order $25$. So in every case there is a normal subgroup of a specified order, and we can go on from there.